# How Do I Add Labels To My Python Script Output?

Tags: python, list

I have little experience with python or coding for that matter. I have a script that outputs random numbers and password. The I want the output file to properly title each section of the text file.

For example,

The way it outputs currently is

```
51008454198044
44148912190091
123password
```

I would like it to be like this

```
**Random Numbers**
51008454198044
44148912190091

**Password**
123password
```

```
    # generate usernames
for i in range(num):

    # construct username
    word1 = random.choice(adjectives)
    word2 = random.choice(nouns)
    #check if word2 is censored
    if word2 in censored:
        i -=1
        continue
    #else make and print the username
    #captilaize first letter
    word1 =word1.title()
    word2 =word2.title()
    username = '{}{}{}'.format(word1, word2, random.randint(1, 99))

    # success
    print(username)
```

Comment: your code and your output dont really fit together?

Comment: What am I missing here? Why not just put in `print('**Random Numbers**')` and `print('**Password**')` before printing the actual things?

Comment: I am using this user's script:
https://github.com/purry03/Username-Generator